# How do I get rid of the "External" label in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My company has enforced a new "External" label that is applied to non-domain senders. This is highly visible in the Inbox which now looks rather cluttered.

How can I get rid of this visual reminder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the label is only applied to the "From" **column** and not to the actual Sender value, you can get around this by simply **defining your own column to replace the default**.

Right click the header of your inbox and open the  **View Settings**. Go to **Columns**, **New Column**, set **Type** to **Formula** and then enter `[From]`. You can also add this or other fields from the full editor. (It also supports functions so if the label is every applied to the field itself in a future update there might still be ways to remove it.)

[image: dialog]

Make sure to add the new column to those shown and move it up to where "From" now is. Remove the original "From".

Close the dialogs and enjoy your inbox free from external hand-holding.

[image: Inbox display]

*Disclaimer: as you're not breaking anything, just changing a display screen I can't think of an IT policy this would actually violate. But you make this modification at your own risk. And be perhaps doubly cautious when opening external emails.*

---

### For Administrators

While outside the scope of this answer, Exchange admins should be able to control this behaviour server-side with PowerShell command `Set-ExternalInOutlook -Enabled $false` as described in [Set-ExternalInOutlook (ExchangePowerShell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-externalinoutlook?view=exchange-ps) on Microsoft Learn.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Single message list format, you won't be able to click on the “From (No External)” header to sort messages. Instead, open the dropdown menu in the top right corner above the message list and select "Arrange by From".

[image]